# Why am I printing different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's different between lines 16 and 17?

```
#user input
annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
portion_saved = float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: "))
total_cost = float(input("Enter the cost of your dream home: "))

#static vars
portion_down_payment = total_cost*.25
monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
r = .04 #annual rate of return

months_to_save = 0
current_savings = 0
investment_return = current_savings * r / 12

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    #current_savings += (current_savings * r / 12) + (portion_saved * monthly_salary)   # Line 16
    current_savings += (investment_return) + (portion_saved*monthly_salary)   # Line 17
    months_to_save += 1
    
print("Number of months: ", months_to_save)
```

I tried running it through [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23user%20input%0Aannual_salary%20%3D%20float%28input%28%22Enter%20your%20annual%20salary%3A%20%22%29%29%0Aportion_saved%20%3D%20float%28input%28%22Enter%20the%20percent%20of%20your%20salary%20to%20save,%20as%20a%20decimal%3A%20%22%29%29%0Atotal_cost%20%3D%20float%28input%28%22Enter%20the%20cost%20of%20your%20dream%20home%3A%20%22%29%29%0A%0A%23static%20vars%0Aportion_down_payment%20%3D%20total_cost*.25%0Amonthly_salary%20%3D%20annual_salary/12%0Ar%20%3D%20.04%20%23annual%20rate%20of%20return%0A%0Amonths_to_save%20%3D%200%0Acurrent_savings%20%3D%200%0Ainvestment_return%20%3D%20current_savings%20*%20r%20/%2012%0A%0Awhile%20current_savings%20%3C%20portion_down_payment%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%23current_savings%20%2B%3D%20%28current_savings%20*%20r%20/%2012%29%20%2B%20%28portion_saved%20*%20monthly_salary%29%0A%20%20%20%20current_savings%20%2B%3D%20investment_return%20%2B%20%28portion_saved*monthly_salary%29%0A%20%20%20%20months_to_save%20%2B%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28%22Number%20of%20months%3A%20%22,%20months_to_save%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=14&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%22120000%22,%22.1%22,%221000000%22%5D&textReferences=false) and the variation happens on step 15 of execution, but I can't quite figure out what's different.

Comment: Using line `16` updates `current_savings` based on the *current* value of `current_savings`, whereas line `17` updates `current_savings` based on the *original* value of `current_savings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `current_savings += investment_return`, it adds the same amount of interest to `current_savings` each time through the loop. That interest is equal to `current_savings * r / 12` calculated *before* you started the loop.

But when you use `current_savings += (current_savings * r / 12)`, you recalculate the interest each time through the loop. So the interest is calculated based on the current value of `current_savings`, which gets bigger each time the loop runs.

In other words, the first one calculates [simple interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest#Simple_interest), and the second one calculates [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest#Compound_interest).